# Entity not saved

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i created my domain-class via editor as usual, i create the controller and some views as usual too.

I use the ui as usual to create an database-entry as usual, and the .save() method returns true.

But no database-row has been insert to the database!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the scaffolding or have you implemented the views/controllers yourself?  What are you using for the data store?

Comment: I suggest you include the relevant sections of code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It was an different Case**

I found

```
static transactional = false
```

on the top of my class.

BS!

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this to your domain object and then print the errors. Save will refuse to save if there is any constraints violation.

```
def user = new User(params)

if (user.save()) {
   return user
}
else {
  user.errors.allErrors.each {
      println it
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you might get more insight if you do save( flush:true, failOnError: true ). This will throw an exception and help you diagnose it if it is hibernate failing down the chain.

Also, you might want to make sure your database settings are right ( i.e., in-memory databases get wiped ). Do you see anything when you call Domain.list() afterwards?